# SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier for loop through an array

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Writing a loop and array that searches text for a word and it comes up with this syntax error I've been looking over the code but can't seem to notice any errors.

```js
jshint multistr:true 

var text = "Usually, solar companies install\
solar panels on roofs but Elon Musk offers an\
entirely different and ingenious approach";

var myName = "Elon";

var hits = [];

for(var i=0; i <= text.length; i++) {
   if(text[i] === 'E') {
       for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {
           hits.push(text[j]);
       }
   }
}

if (hits.length === [0]) {
 console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
 console.log(hits);
}
```

Comment: What is __`hits.length === [0]`__ ? Do you mean __`hits.length === 0`__ ?

Comment: Try using an IDE to spot those syntax error. Jetbrain's Webstorm is pretty good for javascript programming.

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
var jshint_multistr = true;
```

**instead of**

```
jshint multistr:true
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok never mind turns out it was the "jshint multistr:true" at the top. No idea what it does or why it causes an error but codeacademy had it there as a comment which I unsilenced and forgot about.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **jshint** directives in wrong way, you should put it inside **/* */** tag
Try the code below..
 it will work.

```js
/* jshint multistr:true */

var text = "Usually, solar companies install\
solar panels on roofs but Elon Musk offers an\
entirely different and ingenious approach";

var myName = "Elon";

var hits = [];

for(var i=0; i <= text.length; i++) {
   if(text[i] === 'E') {
       for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {
           hits.push(text[j]);
       }
   }
}

if (hits.length === [0]) {
 console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
 console.log(hits);
}
```